# Eclipse/PyDev: Which folders should I add to the System pythonpath?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using PyDev in Eclipse and I am slowly understanding interpreters and python paths.

One question I do have however is when I go to add a new Interpreter in Eclipse/Pydev I get the below warning message in the "Selection needed" window.

> Select the folders to be added to the SYSTEM Pythonpath!
>
> **IMPORTANT: The folders for your Projects should NOT be added here, but in your project configuration**
>
> Check:http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for more details.

[image]

I don't understand the warning message, which one of these is the folder for my projects? Can anyone provide any additional information or guidance?

Which of the above options should I typically select and why, which should I not select and why?

The message seems to say to me, be very careful which one of the below options you select but does not seem to provide good information as to which.

I have read the linked page but maybe I'm missing something

Deepend

Comment: You must separate the python sources and your projects sources. I guess that "/Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace/..." are project folders and shouldn't be added here.

Comment: I think I have added them every time so...

Comment: @LoïcG. If you put your comment into an answer I would be happy to accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Done and you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must separate the python sources and your projects sources.

I guess that "/Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace/..." are project folders and shouldn't be added here.

Comment: Indeed, path resources for the interpreter must be separate from those of a project, i.e. you do not want path resources from a specific project to creep into the global paths picked up by many other projects. Add your project folders in `PyDev - PYTHONPATH` from the project settings.